# How can we to create an exercise environment like this:

Tags: exercises, fbox

How can we to create an exercise environment like this:
[image]

I tried

> \definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.7,0}
>
> \fboxset{rounded,border-color=orange}

But it wasn't success.

Comment: The tcolorbox package might be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following example, I used `\newtcbtheorem` from the `tcolorbox` package. Spacing, colors, numbering scheme and more can of course be adjusted further to suit your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=chapter,]{mydef}{Definition}%
              {enhanced jigsaw,% 
               sharp corners,%
               boxrule=0pt,%
               fonttitle=\color{orange}\bfseries,%
               colback=orange!20!white,%
               colbacktitle=orange!20!white,%
               borderline north={2pt}{0pt}{orange},%
               borderline south={2pt}{0pt}{orange},%
               theorem style=plain
               }{th}

    
    
\begin{document}

\chapter{chapter title}

\begin{mydef}{}{label}
contents
\end{mydef}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, if I want to change 1.1 to 2.1 (or any other number), how could I do that?

Comment: Depends on what "2" represents here. In the example code, "1.1"  stands for "chapter 1.definition 1" as I guessed, the first number was the chapter number. If that's not the case, please explain, what the first of the two numbers actually stands for.

Comment: Because I want to write for a post, which not any chapter there.

Comment: But what does the first number correspond to? A section, an exercise,...? Does it have any meaning? What does "post" refer to in this context? Please explain.

Comment: For example, in my post there is \section and \subsection. I use this in section (the second) and subsection (the first), so I want to get 1.1 into 2.1. That mean the first number is for the section, and the second for subsection..

Comment: If you number a definition using "2.1"  and "2" is the section number and "1" is the subsection number, where is the definition's number? Wouldn't you need a format such as "2.1.3" for the third definition in the first subsection of the second section? If that's the output you want, using `number within=subsection` instead of `number within=chapter` should work.

Comment: Thank you, it work now.